# Jenkins- How to create Jenkins jobs, build jobs with maven(build) and git(SCM) programatically using java

Tags: java, jenkins

I'm new to Jenkins, I want to automate the Jenkins manual procedure like creating a new job, configuring job like (scm, build, post build activities), Build Now,
verifying the build status. I'm a java developer so I wanted to do above all Jenkins activities through java programmatically. 
Please provide some examples or any references to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

**Groovy** is preferred to define jobs programmatically through a DSL.

Depending or your Jenkins version you can use:

- [job-dsl-plugin](http://job-dsl-plugin) (all jenkins versions):

  ```
  job('PROJ-unit-tests') {
    scm {
      git(gitUrl)
    }
    triggers {
      scm('*/15 * * * *')
    }
    steps {
        maven('-e clean test')
    }
  ```

  }

or

- [Jenkins declarative pipelines](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/hello-world/#java) style (since jenkins 2):

  ```
  pipeline {
    agent { docker 'maven:3.3.3' }
   stages {
     stage('build') {
       steps { sh 'mvn --version' }
     }
   }
  ```

  }